# Do herbs like Elfroot grow back?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

While there seems to be a lot of Elfroot around, at least in the first area after the prologue, upgrading my potions has a rather steep price and requires large amounts of Elfroot even just for the first upgrade of the healing potion.

Do herbs like Elfroot grow back after some time, or are they gone once harvested and there is no benefit to revisiting areas where I already harvested all of the herbs?

Comment: In DA2 they won't regrow, so I think it should be the same here.

Comment: @rlecaro2 In DA2 they weren't commodities you harvested and carried with you though. You discovered a "cash" and pointed craftsmen to it. DA:I herbs look a lot more like they did in DA:O.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my experience in the Hinterlands, elfroot does grow back after some time.  I harvested the southeastern region yesterday and when I started up today, most of the areas had more elfroot.  Iron and drakestone will also replensish over time.  I believe several of the other types will regrow over time.

Comment: I can confirm this.  The Smuggler's Cave has a good supply of iron and drakestone, I cleaned it out the first time I was there.  Recently I ran back by, and the resources had replenished; sadly the chests had not.

Comment: Some of the common herbs like Elfroot seem to grow back so fast that I have harvested them twice in the same session, like maybe 30 minutes or an hour.